# joedixon/laravel-translation error during installation in Laravel: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, laravel, language-translation, laravel-6.2

I am facing this error while installing joedixon/laravel-translation library in my application. I tried many things I couldn't find any solution. Please help me here.

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Unsupported operand types

  at /var/www/html/joedixon/vendor/joedixon/laravel-translation/routes/web.php:3
    1| <?php
    2| 
  > 3| Route::group(config('translation.route_group_config') + ['namespace' => 'JoeDixon\\Translation\\Http\\Controllers'], function ($router) {
    4|     $router->get(config('translation.ui_url'), 'LanguageController@index')
    5|         ->name('languages.index');
    6| 
    7|     $router->get(config('translation.ui_url').'/create', 'LanguageController@create')
    8|         ->name('languages.create');
    9| 

  Exception trace:

  1   require()
      /var/www/html/joedixon/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:78

  2   Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom()
      /var/www/html/joedixon/vendor/joedixon/laravel-translation/src/TranslationServiceProvider.php:74
```

Comment: I don't know it is in joedixon/laravel-translation library. This error occurs while installing this library using this command "composer require joedixon/laravel-translation".

Comment: And I don't think it is wrong because I have install this library in fresh new laravel. But the one on which I am trying to install is laravel 6 in which I am not able to install  this library.

Comment: https://github.com/joedixon/laravel-translation/issues/132 it looks like the package author did not specify a Laravel version requirement constraint and it currently is broken in L8

Comment: yes i saw this but in my fresh laravel version it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Basically what the error is saying is that `config('translation.route_group_config')` returned something that's not an array, this is of course not your code so you don't control it but it might be worth deleting any config files you have for laravel translation in your `config` path to see if it just falls back to using the package provided one

Comment: This I tried nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the package, running `php artisan optimize:clear`, and installing it again. The package installs on fresh Laravel 8 project, but if you're are upgrading, I've also encountered this issue. Deleting all caches helped, the package then installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in vendor\joedixon\laravel-translation\routes  Add :
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
then run :composer require joedixon/laravel-translation